# Magento module migration from 1.9 to 2.3 using code migration tool

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, code-migration

I want to migrate one community module which i downloaded from here https://github.com/Marko-M/Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts/

I am following the steps given over https://github.com/magento/code-migration
First 3 steps ran properly without giving any warning or any kind of error.
During php code migration, i am getting warnings for mapping files.
When i got to config.xml it is not converted prodperly and i am getting error when i want to enable the module created in Magento 2.
The error is Element 'modules': This element is not expected.
Line: 42

Verify the XML and try again.
[image]

Can any body help me what to do with this?
Code in config.xml is

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts>
</modules>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
            <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block</class>
        </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
            <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Helper</class>
        </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
    </helpers>
    <models>
        <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
            <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model</class>
        </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <product>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Catalog_Product</product>
                <product_link>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Catalog_Product_Link</product_link>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <inchoo_customlinkedproducts_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts</module>
                <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </inchoo_customlinkedproducts_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <inchoo_customlinkedproducts before="Mage_Adminhtml">Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Adminhtml</inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                <file>inchoo_customlinkedproducts.xml</file>
            </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                <file>inchoo_customlinkedproducts.xml</file>
            </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <catalog_product_prepare_save>
            <observers>
                <inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    <class>inchoo_customlinkedproducts/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogProductPrepareSave</method>
                </inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_prepare_save>
        <catalog_model_product_duplicate>
            <observers>
                <inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    <class>inchoo_customlinkedproducts/observer</class>
                    <method>catalogModelProductDuplicate</method>
                </inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
            </observers>
        </catalog_model_product_duplicate>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Comment: Probably your generated xml for m2 contains wrong data, you should paste its content to get a better answer

Comment: I have added config.xml code in question. Please check. Also i am getting mapping error while runing phpcode migrate command. How to overcome that?

Comment: @SantiBM Can  u help?

Comment: This is the m1 config.xml right? If you try to enable the module in m2 with this xml it will complain as its expecting different content, try showing us the migration errors

Comment: I did not get any migration error when i did migration for layout and config. Adding image in post , i got error during phpcode convert

Comment: Im not sure if i understand well, but by looking at the image and reading how the convert tool works: <src> - Directory that contains custom Magento 1.x code that is intended to be migrated. The code must follow the Magento 1.x directory structure. Magento 1.x core files must not be included. 

I can see in the image that the src file looks in a m2 folder structure rather than a m1 (app/code/community)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109825/discussion-between-nafisa-and-santibm).